# Github Pages is Not Loading Specific Folders

Tags: static-libraries, github-pages

I'm trying to use github-pages to host an online version of a spatial programming course, however the static files for stuff like CSS and JS aren't loading properly.

e.g. https://esda-spatial.github.io/Course-Site/tutorials/03%29%20Working%20with%20Vector%20Data.html

[image: what the website currently looks like]

Whereas when I open the same file locally it appears like this:

[image: preview of what the website should look like]

When I inspect the network tab I can see that the CSS and JS files are 404'ing when requested, and I can't access them either - e.g. https://esda-spatial.github.io/Course-Site/_static/jquery.js.

However, when I try accessing them directly from the repo everything is fine - e.g. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ESDA-Spatial/Course-Site/master/_static/jquery.js

Github pages itself has been set up to read directly from the root repository of the master branch as well.

Any help solving this would be much appreciated

Comment: I have the same question and nobody answer yet. 